# Querying neo4j to get references within resources structure

Tags: neo4j, cypher

With the following query :-

```
MATCH (a) WHERE a.qid = "nm1" AND (a.unmanaged IS NULL OR a.unmanaged = false)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) // for only outward relationships of 'a'
RETURN a as resources, collect(r) as references
```

I am getting resources and references separately which I later merge using a logic.

Is there anyway I can tweak this query such that it returns me all merged by itself?

PS:- Merge in the sense, ith of references as value to key "references" in ith of resources.

**An Example of resources:-**

```
{
  "identity": 0,
  "labels": [
    "cloudInfra"
  ],
  "properties": {
      "region": "Asia"
      "metrics": {},
      "qid": "nm1",
  },
  "elementId": "0"
}
```

**An Example of references :-**

```
[
{
  "identity": 7,
  "start": 1,
  "end": 7,
  "type": "LOCATION_HAS_ES",
  "properties": {
    "_fromUniqueId": "location-c4ff53c9-6122-4cb8-b6f2-466bd86056de",
    "_edgeType": "LOCATION_HAS_ES",
    "_toUniqueId": "env-da691052-c21b-4efb-aa44-ff59efaa79db"
  },
  "elementId": "7",
  "startNodeElementId": "1",
  "endNodeElementId": "7"
},
{
  "identity": 5,
  "start": 1,
  "end": 5,
  "type": "LOCATION_HAS_ES",
  "properties": {
    "_fromUniqueId": "location-c4ff53c9-6122-4cb8-b6f2-466bd86056de",
    "_edgeType": "LOCATION_HAS_ES",
    "_toUniqueId": "env-179b4b3c-d170-44f0-8800-ae0bdba56f8b"
  },
  "elementId": "5",
  "startNodeElementId": "1",
  "endNodeElementId": "5"
},
{
  "identity": 1,
  "start": 1,
  "end": 3,
  "type": "LOCATION_HAS_ES",
  "properties": {
    "_fromUniqueId": "location-c4ff53c9-6122-4cb8-b6f2-466bd86056de",
    "_edgeType": "LOCATION_HAS_ES",
    "_toUniqueId": "env-beacfc97-1e99-4fcc-888b-3c16e06ad609"
  },
  "elementId": "1",
  "startNodeElementId": "1",
  "endNodeElementId": "3"
},
]
```

**Expected merge:-**

```
{
  "identity": 0,
  "labels": [
    "cloudInfra"
  ],
  "properties": {
      "region": "Asia"
      "metrics": {},
      "qid": "nm1",
      "references": [
        {
          "identity": 7,
          "start": 1,
          "end": 7,
          "type": "LOCATION_HAS_ES",
          "properties": {
            "_fromUniqueId": "location-c4ff53c9-6122-4cb8-b6f2-466bd86056de",
            "_edgeType": "LOCATION_HAS_ES",
            "_toUniqueId": "env-da691052-c21b-4efb-aa44-ff59efaa79db"
          },
          "elementId": "7",
          "startNodeElementId": "1",
          "endNodeElementId": "7"
        },            
        {
          "identity": 5,
          "start": 1,
          "end": 5,
          "type": "LOCATION_HAS_ES",
          "properties": {
            "_fromUniqueId": "location-c4ff53c9-6122-4cb8-b6f2-466bd86056de",
            "_edgeType": "LOCATION_HAS_ES",
            "_toUniqueId": "env-179b4b3c-d170-44f0-8800-ae0bdba56f8b"
          },
          "elementId": "5",
          "startNodeElementId": "1",
          "endNodeElementId": "5"
        },
        {
          "identity": 1,
          "start": 1,
          "end": 3,
          "type": "LOCATION_HAS_ES",
          "properties": {
            "_fromUniqueId": "location-c4ff53c9-6122-4cb8-b6f2-466bd86056de",
            "_edgeType": "LOCATION_HAS_ES",
            "_toUniqueId": "env-beacfc97-1e99-4fcc-888b-3c16e06ad609"
          },
          "elementId": "1",
          "startNodeElementId": "1",
          "endNodeElementId": "3"
        },
     ],
  },
  "elementId": "0"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Show an example in your question.

Comment: @cybersam I mean references as a key in the returned resources instead of two separate field attributes. Here 0...nth of references belongs to 0...nth of resources respectively.

Comment: Still not clear to me what "merge"means. Please update question to explain how you want to "merge" the `resources` and `references` results from your Cypher query, and what you want the resulting data to look like.

Comment: added examples @cybersam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a node or relationship property is a list, the list can only contain "primitive" types (like strings and integers), but not maps or sub-lists. So what you want to do is not possible.

And it is also not good practice to redundantly store a copy of data from a node's relationships into the node. The copied data will become inconsistent as soon as any of the relationships change, get deleted, or new relationships ones are added. You also increase the amount of storage needed. You should just get the relationship data directly from the relationships.

[UPDATE]

On the other hand, if you don't want to store relationship data in `cloudInfra` nodes, but just want to return each matching `cloudInfra` node's properties combined with a `references` list (containing the node's outgoing relationship data), you can do the following. The APOC function [apoc.map.merge](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.0/overview/apoc.map/apoc.map.merge/) is used to combine the data.

```
MATCH (a:cloudInfra) WHERE a.qid = "nm1" AND (a.unmanaged IS NULL OR a.unmanaged = false)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) // for only outward relationships of 'a'
WITH a, COLLECT(r) AS references
RETURN apoc.map.merge(a, {references: references}) AS combination
```

Comment: I am not intending to store in that way. I just want result of query in that way, instead of two columns , just one column "resources" with each element containing its references against key "references". I think it is achievable through cypher query

Comment: See the update to my answer.

Comment: "Unknown function 'apoc.map.merge' (line 8, column 13 (offset: 190))\n\"RETURN apoc.map.merge(resources, {references: references}) AS combination\"\n             ^"
What am I missing?

Comment: If you are not using neo4j 5.x, then you need to install the `apoc` plugin. For example, [here](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/installation/) are the instructions for neo4j 4.4.

Comment: Thanks for solution. Sorry I am unable to upvote. Not enough reputation. Thanks again @cybersam